# Finding fairway and ports from ship track point using R

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial

I have some data points from different ship include lon/lat, time and ID values recorded by AIS machine on ships, I want to use this points values to create line values which indicate the ship track, and then use track lines to find out fairway and ports.

Now I use `trip` package in R to build track data, however, in my data I find that data points from some ships may not continuous, sometimes the data points may lost in a segment track and sometimes the data points are "bad" points(the points in a track jump to a far away location), I need to filter the "bad" points and complete the lost points. When I use the function `speedfilter` in `trip` package to filter the "bad" points, there are two problems:

1. I set the `max.speed`, but a lot of points below this `max.speed` have been found out, is that the problem with CRS system?
2. The speedfilter function always find out the point next to the "bad" point and miss the "bad" point.

Comment: Could you give an example of a good and a bad row? I don't know trip, but if you need to filter why don't you use data.frame or data.table?

Comment: For example, image a road, a people walk on this road and I collect  track point, if the point on this road that is a good point, but if the point jump to other far away road, that is a bad point. I want to filter the bad point by using speed, because if the bad point jump to far away, the speed must be to large. I need compare speed (or other attributes like distance) of the point with that of other points on the same track, thinking simply use data.frame can't find out the bad point.

Comment: Simply, I have point data of different ships, and want to use those spatial  points to get spatial lines which indicate the ships' track, and then using different ship tracks to find fairway on the sea.

Comment: By the way: Did I answer your question? If yes, you can mark it as answered...

Answer (score 1):

You can plot your lat/lng data as spatial lines using leaflet.
Concerning

1. `max.speed`: According to the manual of track `points are tested for speed between previous / next and 2nd previous / next points.` So I think what you observe is on purpose.
2. `speedfilter`: You should be able to solve the problem by always subtracting 1 from the index or shift the return vector.